# Azure Pipeline Ambiguous Selection

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've a private repository in my Azure DevOps.

It was a WebAPI built on .NET 6 preview. But when I try to create a Pipeline for this, These are the options DevOps is offering me.

My application is an ASP.NET Core WebAPI. But here it was mentioned:
"Build and Test ASP.NET Projects targeting .NET Framework".
I  thought Classic ASP.NET is on .NET Framework and ASP.NET Core is for .NET Core.

**Which Pipeline I can use to build my app and why ASP.NET Core has a (.NET Framework) in brackets?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click show more you will find:

[image]

Comment: That's fine. Is there any explanation for - "why ASP.NET Core has a (.NET Framework) in brackets" ?

Comment: The difference is that pipeline uses VSbuild when you select pipeline with .NET Framework and the pipeline without just dotnet command line tool. Could you consider marking my reply as answer and upvote it?

Comment: If you can convince me with a legit technically detailed answer I can certainly upvote and mark as answer. My question was specific about - "why ASP.NET Core has a (.NET Framework) in brackets". Is ASP.NET Core a part of .NET Framework?I was in an impression that ASP.NET Core runs over .NET Core and Classic ASP.NET runs over .NET Framework

Comment: This is simply bad naming. It should be rather `ASP.NET Core (Visual Studio Build)`. And not, ASP.NET Core is not part of .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Until today these templates do not work for modern net 5.0+ apps.
This is what should be done
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive